# with limit(20) it runs only the first 20 values of DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal, drupal-7

In this lines of code it selects only the first 20 but i want the first time select the first 20 and then the other and other and so on :'(
How I can solve this problem?

```
function something_cron()
  $query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->orderBy('wid')
    ->fields('wa', array('variables', 'type', 'severity',
  'message', 'wid', 'timestamp'))
    ->limit(20);
  $result = $query->execute();

  // Loop through each item and add to $row.
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    someother();
  }
```

I also want to avoid this PagerDefault but i cannot..

Comment: Thats why you need **offset**

Comment: WOW really?? I am new in drupal and how i can use this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need PagerDefault if you're not displaying a pager. You can use [orderBy](https://www.drupal.org/node/1848360) and [range](https://www.drupal.org/node/1848368) without it.

If I'm understanding your post, everytime cron is run, you want the first 20 rows of the watchdog table. If this is the case, I would suggest keeping track of the last watchdog id (wid) you got from the table and use that for each subsequent run. Something like:

```
$wid = variable_get('my_last_wid', 0);

$result = db_select('watchdog')
  ->fields('watchdog', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message', 'wid', 'timestamp'))
  ->condition('wid', $wid, '>')
  ->orderBy('wid')
  ->range(0, 20)
  ->execute();

foreach ($result as $watchdog) {
  // do whatever you need to do
}

if (!empty($watchdog)) {
  variable_set('my_last_wid', $watchdog->wid);
}
```

Comment: yes it runs for my first 20 rows. when cron runs i want to run for the next 20 not for the same...

Comment: if i put limit(20) and range(0, 20) is the same thing i want : the second time that cron will run for the 20-40 values and third time that cron runs will run for 40-60..

Comment: So, does my answer seem sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the first run:

```
$query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa')
->extend('PagerDefault')
->orderBy('wid')
->fields('wa', array('variables', 'type', 'severity','message', 'wid', 'timestamp'))
->range(0,20);
$result = $query->execute();
```

And this for the second

```
$query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa')
->extend('PagerDefault')
->orderBy('wid')
->fields('wa', array('variables', 'type', 'severity','message', 'wid', 'timestamp'))
->range(20,20);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Just keep increasing the first parameter of the range function.

What "offset" does is it ignores the first x amount of rows. If you have 100 rows and you want the last 35 you could do "->range(65,35);"

EDIT:
Here's an example how range() works.

http://unska.com/drupal_range.png

Comment: i will put these 2 codes one over the other? When cron runs it runs the same lines of code each time..

Comment: I only added "->offset(20)" after the limit(20) on your example. Try it.

Comment: it shows me that error : Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in

Comment: Alright, I edited my answer. Try changing the limit(20) to range(0,20) and range(20, 20). After that range(40, 20), range(60, 20) etc.

Comment: i change the limit(20) with range (0,20) and it only pushes again the first 20 items

Comment: Yes, range(0,20) is the first 20 (0->20) items. range(20,20) is the 20->40 items. range(40, 20) is the 40->60 items. The first value tells you how many items to skip, and the second value tells you how many items to return after skipping the other items.

Comment: i must write all this values in one db_select?

Comment: i cannot understand. I want to take all the values of the table but i want it when cron runs takes the first 20 and then the 20-40 and then the 40-60 and so on.

Comment: And if you want all values don't use range() at all.

Comment: what i can use ??i want run the first 20 values the the next 20 and then the next 20 adn so on how i can do it?? with limit(20) it takes the first 20 and next it takes again the first 20..... :'( :'( I must solve this thing i need it

Comment: Dude. range(0, 20) = FIRST 20. range(20, 20) = NEXT 20, range(40, 20) NEXT NEXT 20, range(60, 20) = NEXT NEXT NEXT 20 and so forth. It can't be this complicated can it?

Comment: I will write in my code many db_select with different ranges?